# why virtual memory copy on write need to be backed by disk page

Tags: memory-management

reading the copy on write about window's memory management, it is saying that system will find   a free page in the RAM for the shared memory ( be backed immediately by disk page ).

why it is necessary to back the RAM page with disk page ? it is not swapped out, it is just created ?

I remember the RAM page only get swapped when there is not enough RAM page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system needs the guarantee that when a write happens, space **will** be available. You can't fail an allocation now if the system will run out of diskspace later.

That doesn't mean the disk s written to; the page reservation is merely bookkeeping.

Comment: that means for whatever RAM page allocated, there will always be DISK  page allocated at the same time, will that cuase too much overhead?

Comment: @zinking: What do you call "too much bookkeeping"? It's necessary. And the disk part isn't the biggest part of the bookkeeping. The allocation must find an exact virtual address in memory, but for disk you can just update the amount reserved.